# Why do i have to specifically include headers in some OSX frameworks with Eclipse?

Tags: macos, frameworks, header, include, eclipse-cdt

I'm new to OSX and i'm getting used to the way frameworks work.

In c++ projects, when i want to link a preinstalled framework, for example OpenGL.framework, i just type "-framework OpenGL" and i'm good to go.

On the other side, when i copy a new framework into for example /Library/Frameworks, and i go "-framework MyFramework", the framework is linked but i need to manually include the header files.

Why can this be? Aren't the headers supposed to be inside the framework already?
Why do i need to include them for some frameworks but not for others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-framework` is a linker option. It has no effect on the header search path. You can convince yourself that this is the case by trying to remove the `-framework` option for a system framework you are using. You will see that the headers are still found, but there will be missing symbol errors at link time.

The `-F` option can be used to specify additional paths where framework headers are searched. For example, say you have a framework named `MyFramework` containing a header `MyHeader.h`, and install this framework in `/Library/Frameworks`. The header can then be found at `/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/Headers/MyHeader.h`, where `Headers` is a symbolic link to a version specific directory. The actual location of the header would then for example be `/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework/Versions/A/Headers/MyHeader.h`.

To include this header, the `#include` in the source file looks like this:

```
#incude <MyFramework/MyHeader.h>
```

and you can compile the source file using:

```
clang -F/Library/Frameworks foo.cpp -framework MyFramework
```

Note that the location of headers for system frameworks in Mac OS changed a couple of releases ago (I think it started around Xcode 4). The headers used to be within their framework directories, which are mostly in `/System/Library/Frameworks`, but that is not the case anymore. The headers are now in the SDK directories that are part of the Xcode installation.

For example, for Mac OS 10.9, the framework headers are in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`.

Aside from separating files used at build time from files used at runtime, this newer setup has the advantage that you can have multiple SDKs, and can choose to build against specific SDKs. To choose a SDK other than the default, use the `-isysroot` compiler option.

Comment: Well, i kind of understand it, but there must be a kind of auto configuration that allows to not having to specify the header files location for OS pre installed frameworks. Just adding the "-framework" line, the header files are found automatically.

Comment: The `-framework` option really has nothing to do with finding the header files. I edited my answer to elaborate on that some more. The headers for the system frameworks are found because they are part of the SDK, which is part of the header search path by default. If you use other frameworks that are not part of the SDK, you need the `-F` option.

Comment: ok, now everything its clear ^^. Thanks. The reasons of my reasoning are too obscure to describe here.